# External Hosted React JS with plain Javascript and HTML page

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We have a common widget in each of our pages across multiple services, and we want to write a common client-side rendition code in ReactJS for this widget as an external hosted js, such that each of the pages can include this externally hosted JS in their pages to render the widget. But many of these pages are written in different JS frameworks (angular/inferno/typescript/etc) or even in plain vanilla JS. Now pardon me if this is an ignorant question, but I think that ReactJS code can be compiled into javascript using babel, and the bundled js file can then be directly included in any page using any framework(angular/typescript/etc). Is my assumption correct, or will such an approach lead to problems. Any other inputs?

PS: I am very new to any of these JS frameworks, and have only worked on small projects involving plain vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount your react root node (typically `<App/>` ) in any html DOM node. This is what `react-dom` does by

```
render( <App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

which would be a familiar line for you.

Now, coming to how to actually do this. I assume you are using create-react-app.

- Run `npm run build` inside your project folder.
- When it finishes, you will find a bunch of files inside `your-project-folder/build`, including

  - `build/index.html`
  - `build/static/js`, `build/static/css`, etc
- Open the `build/index.html` file in a text editor and study it. I think you will be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: thanks @anand, but can including my JS file on the page conflict with common js libraries and versions used in both places. So lets say my widget JS is written in one version of reactJS and some other js libraries, while the page which includes the externally hosted compiled js for the widget, is written in another version of reactJS and imports different versions of same libraries, I think it can break the overall rendition of the page. Is there a way to go around such an issue.

Comment: My understanding is that it will typically not pollute the global namespace, as all the modules are supposed to be enclosed in closures when compiled to JS. But I am not sure if there is any way to be SURE of this.

Comment: However, if it is any comfort, note that adding react widgets into existing pages is a recommended way to use react https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#adding-react-to-an-existing-application

Comment: From the official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html